# iOS cocoa retain variable block

Tags: ios, cocoa, variables, block, retain

I need to retain a variable inside a block because i have to pass it to a method out of the block. I dont know how to achieve this.

```
__weak MyClass *weakSelf = self;
[myFile addObserver:self block:^
{
       if ([[[weakSelf myFile] newerStatus] cached] )
       {

            [weakSelf performSelector:@selector(myMethod:) withObject:weakSelf.myFile afterDelay:5];
       }

}];
```

I tried also doing this but no success:

```
__block DBFile *myFileFinal;

 __weak MyClass *weakSelf = self;
[myFile addObserver:self block:^
{
       if ([[[weakSelf myFile] newerStatus] cached] )
       {
            __strong MyClass *strongSelf = weakSelf;
            myFileFinal = strongSelf.myFile;
            [weakSelf performSelector:@selector(myMethod:) withObject:myFileFinal afterDelay:5];
       }

}];
```

How can i retain "myFile" for use outside of the block?
Need help please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using an ivar isn't enough?

Comment: Sorry im new in objetive c. What is an ivar?

Comment: Are you sure you're not setting `myFile` to nil somewhere else? Maybe you want to pass `[myFile copy]`.

Comment: an ivar is a global variable

Comment: if i try to use a global variable i get this warning: "capturing self strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle"

Comment: @Imotep an *ivar* is an instance variable.. What we refer to as a *global variable* is usually a static variable accessible by all instances of a class (or even any class).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "How can i retain "myFile" for use outside of the block?"

`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` retains the receiver and arguments until the action is performed.